# WCF: Efficiently consuming large numbers of singleton requests via SQL job?

Tags: sql-server-2005, queue, batch-processing, performance

I'm planning to build a console app to run as part of a SQL 2005 job which will gather records from a database table, create a request object for a WCF service, pass this object to the service for processing, receive a response object, and update a log table with its data. This will be for processing at least several thousand records each time the job step executes.

The WCF service currently exposes a single method which I'd be hitting once for each record in the table, so I imagine I'd want to open a channel to the service, keep it open during processing, then close and dispose and such when complete.

Beyond maintaining the connection, how else could I minimize this console app's performance as a bottleneck? Should I not use a console app and instead try using SQLCLR or some other means to perform this processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably considered Service Broker...

Comment: No; I'm still new to WCF, and also I guess our shop is because using the console app route was suggested to ME. Thanks for this suggestion, I'll look into what this involves.